# Laurel leaves turning gray and black

Tags: leaves, tree-care

I bought a tiny laurel tree in a pot from the shop 3 months ago. It looked happy but after repotting it's starting to wither and the leaves are turning grey.

I tried changing the amount of sunlight and/or water it gets but that doesn't seem to help.

It's on the balcony of a flat facing south in London. I don't think there has been any temperature less than 0 degrees since I got it.

What's going on with it? Is it some disease?

I'm adding some pictures of the damage.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you should try to give it more sun and less water and never water the leaves.

It seems some oidium or similar fungi attack, frequent on lower leaves (on shadows places).

Temperature should not be a problem. (also in case of occasional freezing). In that case you will see entire leaves (overall the plant) orange-brown/grey/brown.

Probably some fungicide could help. Do you plan to use your Laurel for cooking purposes?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I got it for decorative purposes but using the leaves would be a plus, though not having it die is my priority now :)